# 'IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)' Error with OleDbDataReader in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Can anyone tell me why my code is giving me `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException` and `IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)` errors? They're at the same place. The error appears at the `Reader = Command.ExecuteReader()` line. Here is my code:

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim Connection As OleDbConnection
        Dim Command As OleDbCommand
        Dim Reader As OleDbDataReader
        Dim ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\KayJoy\Documents\University\UJ Official Documents\Informatics\2A\P02.accdb"
        Connection = New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
        Connection.Open()
        Dim CommandString As String
        CommandString = "SELECT * FROM Module"
        Command = New OleDbCommand(CommandString, Connection)
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        Reader = Command.ExecuteReader()
        If Reader.HasRows Then
            Do While Reader.Read
                Response.Write(Reader("M_Code") & ",")
                Response.Write(Reader("M_Name") & ",")
                Response.Write(Reader("M_Credit") & "<br/>")
            Loop
        End If
        Command.Connection.Close()
        Command.Dispose()
        Connection.Dispose()
    End If
```

Comment: Try to enclose the  word `Module` in square brackets. `SELECT * FROM [Module]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is causing my OLEDbException, IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E\_FAIL(0x80004005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534284/what-is-causing-my-oledbexception-ierrorinfo-getdescription-failed-with-e-fail)

Comment: It works now, thank you! @equisde